# python - matplotlib - disable plot to screen - set to Agg only

Tags: python

I'm getting this problem (asked about before), and can't see how to fix it:

```
import matplotlib
print dir()
matplotlib.use('Agg')
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
```

gives

This call to matplotlib.use has no effect because the the backend has already been chosen;
use must be called *before* pylab, matplotlib.pyplot, or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.

I can't place the use call any higher. As suggested, I've set $DISPLAY to localhost:0. I quite need to suppress the displayed figures, and, rather, output solely to file.

This is all on a Mac with enthought python.

Thanks!

Comment: I omitted some lines to get the 4-space rule to work (in fact the form was objecting to the inline snippets), e.g. ['matplotlib', 'posn', 'radiusArcmin', 'self', 'sigma']

Comment: Are you sure that what you have isn't working? It should... Where you have the call to `matplotlib.use` should set the backend correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe looking for [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=switch_backend#matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend)?

Alternatively, you might want to [change your matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html).

Comment: Thanks! The matplotlibrc method worked. Though I'd prefer to use something inline/in the code itself. This didn't seem to work: import matplotlib
 #matplotlib.use('Agg')
 from scipy import ndimage
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 #matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend('Agg')
 from matplotlib.patches import Circle

Comment: Hi, can you update the links in your answer, they seem to be outdated/broken.

Comment: Updated links: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.switch_backend.html and https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file